# Select Contiguous Rows for Run Length Encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, run-length-encoding

I have some enormous tables of values, and dates, that I want to compress using run length encoding. The most obvious way (to me) to do this is to select all the distinct value combinations, and the minimum and maximum dates. The problem with this is that it would miss any instances where a mapping stops, and then starts again.

```
Id | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |  DataDate
------------------------------------------
01 |   1    |   2    |   3    | 2000-01-01
01 |   1    |   2    |   3    | 2000-01-02
01 |   1    |   2    |   3    | 2000-01-03
01 |   1    |   2    |   3    | 2000-01-04
01 |   A    |   B    |   C    | 2000-01-05
01 |   A    |   B    |   C    | 2000-01-06
01 |   1    |   2    |   3    | 2000-01-07
```

Would be encoded this way as

```
Id | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |  FromDate |  ToDate
-----------------------------------------------------
01 |   1    |   2    |    3   | 2000-01-01| 2000-01-07
01 |   A    |   B    |    C   | 2000-01-05| 2000-01-06
```

Which is clearly wrong.

What I'd like is a query that would return each set of continuous dates that exist for each set of values.

Alternatively, if I'm looking at this arse-backwards, any other advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't a clue what you're asking here but if you sort your values first you'll get around the problem of a set of data "stopping".

Comment: This is a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem.  What version of SQL Server?  What's the type of `DataDate`?  Note that the ending date [should be exclusive](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Which columns do you care about?  All, any, or a particular one?

Comment: I care about all the columns. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    Id INT,
    Value1 VARCHAR(10), 
    Value2 VARCHAR(10),
    Value3 VARCHAR(10), 
    DataDate DATE
);

INSERT @MyTable 
SELECT 01, '1', ' 2', '3', '2000-01-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 01, '1', ' 2', '3', '2000-01-02' UNION ALL
SELECT 01, '1', ' 2', '3', '2000-01-03' UNION ALL
SELECT 01, '1', ' 2', '3', '2000-01-04' UNION ALL
SELECT 01, 'A', ' B', 'C', '2000-01-05' UNION ALL
SELECT 01, 'A', ' B', 'C', '2000-01-06' UNION ALL
SELECT 01, '1', ' 2', '3', '2000-01-07'

SELECT  Id, Value1, Value2, Value3,
        MIN(DataDate) AS FromDate, MAX(DataDate) AS ToDate
FROM (
    SELECT  x.Id, x.Value1, x.Value2, x.Value3, 
            x.DataDate,
            GroupNum = 
                DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, x.DataDate) -
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.Id, x.Value1, x.Value2, x.Value3 ORDER BY x.DataDate)
    FROM    @MyTable x
) y
GROUP BY Id, Value1, Value2, Value3, GroupNum
```

Results:

```
Id Value1 Value2 Value3 FromDate   ToDate
-- ------ ------ ------ ---------- ----------
1  1       2     3      2000-01-01 2000-01-04
1  1       2     3      2000-01-07 2000-01-07
1  A       B     C      2000-01-05 2000-01-06
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use windowing functions. Try something like this:

```
select 
    id, value1, value2, value3, 
    from_date=update_date, 
    to_date=lead(update_date) over (partition by id order by update_date)
from (
    select 
    t.*
    ,is_changed=
     case when 
        value1 <> lag(value1) over (partition by id order by update_date) or 
          (lag(value1) over (partition by id order by update_date) is null and value1 is not null) or
        value2 <> lag(value2) over (partition by id order by update_date) or 
          (lag(value2) over (partition by id order by update_date) is null and value2 is not null) or
        value3 <> lag(value3) over (partition by id order by update_date) or 
          (lag(value3) over (partition by id order by update_date) is null and value3 is not null) 
     then 1 else 0 end
    from test t
) t2
where is_changed = 1
order by id, update_date
```

Please note that this query relies on the `LAG()` function, and two other things:

- Separate tests for each "value" column; if you have a lot of columns to test, you might consider creating a single hash value to simplify the equality checks
- The "to_date" is identical to the next record's "from_date", which means you might need to test for values using `>= from_date` and `< to_date` to make the run-lengths mutually exclusive

Note that I used the following sample data in my testing:

```
create table test(id int, value1 varchar(3), value2 varchar(3), value3 varchar(3), update_date datetime)

insert into test values
(1, 'A', 'B', 'C', '1/1/2014'),
(1, 'A', 'B', 'C', '2/1/2014'),
(1, 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '3/1/2014'),
(1, 'A', 'B', 'C', '4/1/2014'),
(2, 'D', 'E', 'F', '1/1/2014'),
(2, 'D', 'E', 'F', '6/1/2014')
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, you need windowing functions.  No, this isn't sufficient - this is the equivalent of `GROUP`ing by the partitioned columns, which will return the wrong results.

Comment: My first answer was insufficient. Edited answer does the run-length transform correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  Id, Value1, Value2, Value3, MIN(DataDate) AS FromDate, MAX(DataDate) AS ToDate
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Id, Value1, Value2, Value3
```

Comment: The op is actually _not_ looking for this, although I agree that it appears this way at first glance.